# Using 'OR' in Case statement of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use `||` in JavaScript `Case`

```
function checkingForAB (data) {
   var reply;
   switch (data) {

      case 'A'||'B':
           reply = 'Yes';
           break;
      case 'D':
           reply = 'No';
           break;
      default:
           reply = 'No';

   }
   return reply;

}
```

I have not tried this before. So, I don't know what happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use OR.

Comment: Code actually works.. to my surpise:  https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/4vr9vk56/1/ Shoudn't be marked as duplicate tho. The answer to this question is YES

Comment: @jkris No it doesn't. Try changing `default:` and then do `checkingForAB('B')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try it like this instead...

```
function checkingForAB (data) {
   var reply;
   switch (data) {

      case 'A':
      case 'B':
           reply = 'Yes';
           break;
      case 'D':
           reply = 'No';
           break;
      default:
           reply = 'Yes';

   }
   return reply;

}
```

Comment: Additionially, no need for a `break` in the `default` either.